# how we get a module parameter in a component view in joomla

Tags: joomla

How do I get the module parameter inside a component in Joomla 1.5? I am using this code but it displays an empty result.

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = &JModuleHelper::getModule( 'mod_used_car_image');

$params = new JParameter($module->params);

print_r($params);
```

Comment: What is the value of $module->params? Try var_dump($module->params);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the 'name' of your module, not the 'type' of module.

Let's say you named your module 'Used Car Image', your code should be:

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = &JModuleHelper::getModule( 'Used Car Image');

$params = new JParameter($module->params);

print_r($params);
```

Here's the manual:

http://docs.joomla.org/JModuleHelper/getModule

Answer (score 3):

I got the params value. Use this code to get it:

```
jimport( 'joomla.html.parameter' );
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_name');
$moduleParams = new JRegistry();
$moduleParams->loadString($module->params);
$position = $moduleParams->get('position', '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('modulename');
$params = new JRegistry($module->params);
var_dump($params);
```

That's how to use after joomla 3.0